# Retrieving coefficients from SKLearn StackingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When attempting to retrieve coefficients from a trained StackingClassifier using SKlearn it says that `coefs_` does not exist. This means that it thinks it has not been trained yet. I am able to show that it has been trained by calling predict on both the outter pipeline (getting the correct output) and a single model in the stack (saying it has not been fit yet). How can I get the weights out of this model?

````
>>> a.named_steps['stackingclassifier'].named_estimators['mlp'].coefs_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'coefs_'
>>> a.predict_proba([X])
array([[5.69909808e-05, 1.95316594e-05, 1.06791916e-08, 7.99719342e-06,
        4.16570282e-04, 9.78260604e-04, 7.43104846e-05, 1.15379667e-08,
        9.42032134e-06, 9.98103331e-01, 1.21851461e-04, 1.61161070e-04,
        1.97925333e-05, 3.46306792e-07, 3.04140522e-05]])
>>> a.named_steps['stackingclassifier'].named_estimators['mlp'].predict_proba([X])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jbiloki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 1104, in predict_proba
    check_is_fitted(self)
  File "/home/jbiloki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/home/jbiloki/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1020, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This MLPClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.```
````

Answer (score 0):

After reading further through the source code I found that using `clf.estimators` for some reason is wrong and `clf.estimators_` has the actual trained estimators... I could still use a reason for this but to extract the coefficients you can use:

```
pipeline = joblib.load('yourmodel.model')
#Coefs for the first model, iterate over estimators_ for the rest
pipeline['stackingclassifier'].estimators_[0].coef_
```