# How to obtain the coefficient estimates in StackingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, StackingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Create Base Learners
base_learners = [
                 ('rf_1', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)),
                 ('rf_2', KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5))             
                ]

# Initialize Stacking Classifier with the Meta Learner
clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=base_learners, final_estimator=LogisticRegression())
```

How can I look at the stacking coefficients in `clf` (i.e., the logistic regression coefficients)? Based on the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678518/retrieving-coefficients-from-sklearn-stackingclassifier), I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
pipeline = joblib.load('clf')
#Coefs for the first model, iterate over estimators_ for the rest
pipeline['stackingclassifier'].estimators_[0].coef_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

You forgot to fit the classifiers in order to get their attributes

---

### Working Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, StackingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Create Base Learners
base_learners = [
    ('rf_1', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)),
    ('rf_2', KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5))
]

# Initialize Stacking Classifier with the Meta Learner
clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=base_learners,
                         stack_method='predict',
                         final_estimator=LogisticRegression())

# You forget to fit the classifiers in order to get the attributes
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.final_estimator_.coef_)  # Logistic Regression Coefficients
# RandomForestClassifier .. you can access its attributes by .name_of_attribute
print(clf.named_estimators_['rf_1'])
# KNeighborsClassifier .. you can access its attributes by .name_of_attribute
print(clf.named_estimators_['rf_2'])
print(clf.estimators_)  # All estimators in a list
```

### Output:

```
[[-2.68962706 -2.69561738]
 [ 0.22543939 -0.01107915]
 [ 2.46418768  2.70669652]]
RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)
KNeighborsClassifier()
[RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42), KNeighborsClassifier()]
```

---

Also bear in mind to change `stack_method` parameter according to your need [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65973317/6365112).